# How to find a CDF of a composite random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am given a composite random variable $X$, "composite" meaning that $X$ is the random variable that has both discrete and continuous components, with the probability distributions:

$$\begin{cases}P(a<X<b) = \frac{b-a}{2} & \text{if $0<a<b<1$ } \\ P(X=i) = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{i+1} & \text{if $i=1,2,\dotsc$} & \end{cases}$$

How can one write CDF of $X$?

---

EDIT 1.

Given the hints in the comment section I have found $F_1(x)$ and $F_2(x)$ as below:

$F_1(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if $x<0$} \\ x & \text{if $0<x<1$} \\1 & \text{if $x>1$}\end{cases}$

$F_2(x) = 1 - \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^i \;\; \text{for $i=1,2,\dotsc$}$

Hence, the cdf will be given by $F_X(x) = \frac{1}{2} F_1(x) + \frac{1}{2} F_2(x)$.

The reason why I wanted to obtain the cdf in the first place was to then generate random variables using inverse method. Would the following algorithm work?

Following @Henry's answer about the coin tossing:

- generate uniform random variable $U_1 \sim U(0,1)$
- if $U_1<\frac{1}{2}$ then output $X=U_1$
- if $U_1\geq \frac{1}{2}$ then output $X=F_2^{-1}(U)$

Not sure about the last step though. Can I even inverse it when its discrete?

Comment: not sure this would add up to $1$ though?

Comment: @gt6989b The first gives $\mathbb P(0<X<1)=\frac12$ and the second gives $\mathbb P(X \in \{1,2,3,\ldots\})=\frac12$, which add up to $1$

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

Consider the two independent random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$, and find the cumulative distribution functions $F_1(x)=\mathbb P(X_1 \le x)$ and $F_2(x)=\mathbb P(X_2 \le x)$ when

$$\begin{cases}\mathbb P(a<X_1<b) = b-a & \text{if $0<a<b<1$ } \\ \mathbb  P(X_2=i) = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{i} & \text{if $i=1,2,\dotsc$} & \end{cases}$$

i.e. double the probabilities in the original question.

Then independently toss a fair coin to decide whether $X=X_1$ or $X=X_2$, so mutually exclusively each with probability $\frac12$.  You can then say, using the law of total probability,  $$F(x)=\mathbb P(X \le x) = \frac12 \mathbb P(X_1 \le x)+ \frac12\mathbb P(X_2 \le x)= \frac12 F_1(x) + \frac12 F_2(x)$$

Comment: I still have a bit of a problem. I follow your logic for the first part as well as for the final part. However, I still find the $F_1(x)$ quite difficult. In previous examples I had a pdf function given quite explicitly - and all I had to do was integrate. Here I'm not sure what to do with the probabilities $\mathbb P(a<X_1<b)$ and $\mathbb  P(X_2=i)$. Could you help me with that as well?

Comment: @bajun65537: $X_1$ has a uniform distribution on $(0,1)$ while $X_2$ has a geometric distribution